# How to add eclipse project to existing git repo?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I already have an existing project in Eclipse that I want to add to my team's github repo. The github repo is empty right now. What's the best way to add this project to our github repo? I was thinking of `git clone`ing our repo into the workspace folder (parent to the project in question) and then adding the project files using `git add`, then `pushing` the changes. Would that work, or is there a better way to do this (perhaps with EGit)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add a remote to the project, and then push to it.

For example, you can do (from inside the project directory)

```
git init # if you haven't already
git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com:.....
git push -u origin master
```

there should be a way to do that from the eclipse plugin too, but I find it easiear to do it from the command line.. :)

By the way, remember to add all the IDE-specific files to `.gitignore`, to avoid pushing garbage to the world: they usually are  `.project`, `.classpath` and directories like `bin/*`,`.settings/*` ...

Comment: yes, if you didn't do it already.. it basically creates an empty repository you can commit to

Comment: you're welcome.. by t he way, of course, you have to commit changes, before pushing, with the usual ``git add -A``/``git commit`` (or using eclipse plugin)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18762/discussion-between-lanaru-and-redshadow)

Comment: @redShadow np was just  too slow to answer :)