# Add existing local eclipse project to BRANCH within existing GitHub repo

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I'm in a team that has a GitHub repository.  I have my own branch.

I have created a local Eclipse project on my workstation.  Now I'd like to add that project to the GitHub repo, but specifically within my branch.

I have worked through [How to add eclipse project to existing git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131366/how-to-add-eclipse-project-to-existing-git-repo), but I don't want to push to master, and I can't see what I need to do differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to push to some other branch, which does not have the same name, you an use :

```
git push <remote> <source branch on local>:<dest branch on remote>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to your branch using command 
`git checkout your-branch-name`  and then commit your eclipse project to it

Comment: thanks.  Locally, I am on master.  I want my local project to end up in testbranch in github.  I did `git checkout testbranch` and then `git push -u origin testbranch` which gave me _Branch testbranch set up to track remote branch testbranch from origin.
Everything up-to-date_  I definitely have new files in local master...  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `git push -u origin master` gives _error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/turbomam/testrepo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details._

Comment: I re-did `git add`, `git commit` and `git push`.  Now my local files are in the desired remote branch.  Thanks.

Comment: Arpit, something in this process deleted my local files.  Let me know if you're still paying attention to this thread.

Comment: Yes I am , Can you please do   "git status"  and check ?

Comment: thanks.  I recovered my code with the reflogs.  if you're still interested in going over this, we could chat in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58165/eclipse2githibbranch tomorrow ?

Comment: So I guess when you are checking out the other branch you will not see the code thats present in testbranch

Answer (score 0):

Master branch from your *local* repo can be pushed into whatever branch you would like into a remote **but** assuming you don't want to have differing names of branches between your local repo and the remote then just checkout a new branch on your local starting from the remote master branch and then push it into your github repo.