# How to add a java Project created in eclipse to github repository>

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I am new to github.
I have created java project in eclipse (eg:- DateTester).
And I have created a github repository (eg:- SampleProject).

How can I add the DateTester project to github repository (SampleProject)

Comment: In the _Git Repositories_ view clone your GitHub repository, copy the project or project content into the directory of the newly cloned directory (this step should be done outside of Eclipse), delete the project, right-click the cloned repository and choose _Import Projects..._. Maybe it is easier with the GitHub plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to solve the problem through the console.

```
git init # if you haven't already
git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com:.....
git push -u origin master
```

reference question: [How to add eclipse project to existing git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131366/how-to-add-eclipse-project-to-existing-git-repo)

Then you can first commit and then push your changes via eclipse

```
Rightclick on Project
 -> Team
  -> Commit...

Rightclick on Project
 -> Team
  -> Remote
   -> Push...
```

Comment: This requires Git to be installed on the command line. Why not do the steps with Eclipse?

Comment: Yes you need git to be installed. But i think there ist no better way

Comment: Eclipse contains JGit which is a Git implementation in Java. There is no need to install another Git implementation and learn Git command line commands. The better way is to use Eclipse JGit/EGit without installing additional software.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below simple basic steps as well

Step 1 : git clone github repository

```
    https://github.com/XXXXX/SampleProject.git
```

Step 2 : go into clone direcory

Step 3 : copy and paste your project(DateTester) into clone direcory

step 4 : add or update .gitignore file with

`/target/
.classpath
.gitignore
.project
.settings/`

step 5 : run follwoing command from cmd or from terminal

`git add .
git commit -m"Your commit massage"
git push
git status`

step 6 : reimport project into eclipse

Comment: I can see in your answer, you have used some sort of commands.

Do i need to install any additional tool for that.

Comment: @Manomohan Yes, but which is not necessary, because you can do the same also with Eclipse.

Comment: You have to install Git  as per your OS

Comment: @GovindParashar No, you don't have to. Eclipse contains JGit which is a Git implementation in Java. The steps can be done with Eclipse. Some steps can be skipped doing it with Eclipse. See [EGit User Guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide).

Comment: @howlger, I was referring the link you have mentioned in the comments. It seems that for older version of eclipse. Is that true?

I am using eclipse "neon"

Comment: Neon is pretty old, please upgrade. In principle, it should also work in Neon, but a lot has improved in EGit since then. The user guide should refer to the current version.